# How can I access a public class that is instantiated in my main form from a usercontrol in that form?

Tags: c#, mysql, forms, inheritance, user-controls

I have an issue with a nullpointerexception being thrown from my Usercontrol when I try to access a function that is embedded in a class that is created in my MainForm.

This is how it looks:

```
public MySqlPlannerFunctions sqlPlanner;

public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        #region "conString"
        MySqlMain sqlMain = new MySqlMain("root", "*******", 
                                          "opcnewest", "localhost", "3306");
        #endregion
        sqlPlanner = new MySqlPlannerFunctions(sqlMain);
    }
```

With the constructor for MySqlMain I just fill in the data for my connectionstring. Then i create the instance of sqlPlanner and in that constructor i throw in my MySqlMain class so that I can access it directly from the sqlPlanner class. Hope this makes sense.

```
    MySqlMain sqlMain;

    public MySqlPlannerFunctions(MySqlMain SqlMain)
    {
        this.sqlMain = SqlMain;
    }
```

Then in my Usercontrol which will be using sqlPlanner the most it looks like this.

```
    Form1 myParent;

    public PlanningControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        myParent = (Form1)this.ParentForm;
        
    } 

    private void PlanningControl_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dtp_selectedDTFrom = planner_dtp_FromDate.Value.Date;
        dtp_selectedDTTo = planner_dtp_ToDate.Value.Date;

        try
        {
            dS = new DataSet();
            dS = myParent.sqlPlanner.GetPlanInInterval(dtp_selectedDTFrom,                   dtp_selectedDTTo);
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        { 
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        FillListView(dS, planner_lv_Plan);

    }
```

My nullpointerexepction occurs when I try to call the function myParent.sqlPlanner.GetPlanInInterval(data, data);

I've been searching around the internet for a couple of hours and cant find any solutions. So I really hope that someone here can help me and other that might run into the same issue.

Am I doing this the wrong way, is my way of handling the SQL classes just completly retarded or whatever you can come up with that can make me a better developer.

## EDIT

I got asked what is inside the GetPlanInInterval function and this is it:

```
    public DataSet GetPlanInInterval(DateTime from, DateTime to)
    {
        DataSet dS;
        string sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + prod_planning + " WHERE date >= @from AND =< @to";
        MySqlCommand cmd = sqlMain.CreateCommand(sqlQuery);
        if (cmd != null)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@from", from.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@to", to.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));

            dS = new DataSet();
            dS = sqlMain.Select(prod_planning, cmd);

            if (dS != null) return dS;                
        }
        return null;             
    }
```

And in sqlMain.Select() it looks like this:

```
    public DataSet Select(string table, MySqlCommand sqlCommand)
    {
        DataSet dS;
        
        if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
        {
            sqlDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
            sqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand = sqlCommand;

            dS = new DataSet();
            sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dS, table);

            sqlDataAdapter.Dispose();
            sqlCommand.Dispose();
            
            this.CloseConnection();
            
            return dS;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What about making `MySqlPlannerFunctions`'s methods static? You won't need to instantiate it then.

Comment: what is inside `GetPlanInInterval` ?

Comment: and perhaps this line : `MySqlMain sqlMain = new MySqlMain("root",...` should be moved to `MySqlPlannerFunctions` instead of passing it to the constructor.

Comment: How can i write more then 500 characters, when i paste the code of GetPlanInterval its too many characters... Im passing it this way because in the feature i want administrators to be able to configure there database connection in the form. And i dont want to create a new connection with MySqlPlanner (I think) since i will have more classes like this one and it seems like a waste to create the connectionstring and SqlConnection with every class?!

Comment: @Jonesy would this be possible if you now look at how i use the functions i added after the #EDIT ?

Comment: Btw, the Static comment did the trick, now i got to learn when that can come in handy. Never used it before! Thank you!